# Run Excel Macro from Outlook, Based on Email Subject

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I'm trying to set up an automated process for when I receive a email in Outlook containing "subject" it automatically fires off a macro
in Excel and run a macro I have set up in Excel. How can this be accomplished?

Can provide more information if necessary - thanks!

this is the code I used

```
Public Sub Main_function_Auto(Item As Outlook.MailItem)


Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
 Dim ExWbk As Workbook
 Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\x\Desktop\CRAWLER\zxc crawler\xx zz - Production.xlsm")
 ExApp.Visible = True

ExWbk.Application.Run "mainFun.Main_function_Auto"

 ExWbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

the error start at

```
Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
```

Comment: You could also replace your code concept to **Late Binding**

Comment: how to do it. please help

Answer (score 1):

Select Tools, References and set a reference to the Microsoft Excel xx.x library.

Comment: i already tick that. same error

Comment: What precisely is the error?